# Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 is not pinged

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I created a VM on Windows Azure. My actions

1) "File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)" set On

2) Windows Wirewall set Off

It still does not ping.

UPD: The network is working properly.

Comment: Resolved: the end point must be added to port 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by `not pinged`?

ICMP as protocol is **disabled/blocked** at Azure LoadBalancer level. So no matter what you do in your VM, you will never get ICMP traffic from the Internet inside the VM. The only way to get ISMP traffic into a VM is via [Azure Virtual Network, and Azure Connect](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/networking/) and from a valid joined computer.

Your actions (1) and (2) will help you get ICMP traffic from either:

- Another Virtual Machine in the same Cloud Service
- Another Virtual Machine in the same Virtual Network
- Your computer, if it is part of the same Virtual Network
- Your Computer if it **and** the target VM are in the same Group from Windows Azure Connect

** UPDATE **

After clarifying the question, you still will never be able to successfully execute `ping whatever.cloudapp.net`. In order to "make visible iis site", you need to [add an Endpoint to your VM](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/setup-endpoints/) from the portal or the [Management API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157187.aspx) for the port you need. In your case - port 80.

Comment: i use [ping myvm.cloudapp.net] command. My purpose - make visible my iis site